# Using Client Side Rendering for Calendar Views

Tags: development, farm-solution, client-side-rendering

I'm following the [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) article; but *instead of apply CSR code to a `ListView`*, my objective is using CSR for apply it to a `SPCalendarView` *(Default view)*.

What I'm trying to accomplish is get the `SPCalendarItems` inside of `SPCalendarView` control and *depending on a **condition**,* add an anchor HTML element *(i.e) `<a href='#'>Link</a>`*

Example:

Let's say that we have a `Calendar` List (with some recurrent and/or non-recurrent events).

The **condition** is:

> If the day hasn't events on it add an html anchor element (with a link to New Form) *For add a new event*.

With the following code *supplied by the link source*:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
 Templates: {
 Footer: function(ctx) {
      console.log(ctx);
      return "Hello world from " + ctx.ListTitle + "!";
    }
  }});
```

I'm getting this error:

> `SPClientTemplates is not defined`

Error may be caused because `ListView` and `SPCalendarView` are different;  *I tested on a ListView (as the article shows and there's no error).*

I searched on internet but I'm unable to find CRS code used on a `Calendar` view.

There's a way of accomplish this requirement?

---

*I hope not change the scope of this question, but I'm open to get an C# solution for this (working on a Farm webpart).*

Comment: Sorry to asking in old thread. According to [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220045.aspx), "The JSLink property is not supported on Survey or Events lists. A SharePoint calendar is an Events list." So did you find any workaround?

Comment: @MarkL no problem with asking in a old post :) unfortunately I can't remember in which project this requirement is applied "and so, I cannot remember how I solve this _in another way_" :(

Answer (score -1):

There is no file clienttemplates.js on calendar view page, so Calendar List View in SharePoint 2013 not support CSR.
Check the below article. It might help you to solve your problem:

[Calendar list view SharePoint 2013 customization](https://spdevnews.blogspot.com/2019/01/calendar-list-view-sharepoint-2013.html)